# Webservices WCF and XML

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, wcf

First I would like to thank you in advance.

What I am trying to do is load an XML file into my WCF application and display the XML 
Here is what I have done so far

My XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?> 
<DocumentElement>
      <Products>
          <productID>1</productID> 
          <productname>Chai</productname> 
          <categoryID>1</categoryID> 
          <UnitsInStock>39</UnitsInStock> 
          <CategoryName>Beverages</CategoryName> 
      </Products>    
</DocumentElement>
```

My `Service.svc` looks like this:

```
public class Service : IService
{
    public string GetXMLData(string value)
    {
       XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(Properties.Resources.Test);
       return xDocument;
    }
}
```

My `IService` is

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
     [OperationContract]
     [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
                BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, 
                UriTemplate = "MyHttpGetData/{value}")]
     string GetXMLData(string value);
}
```

This is not giving me the output I was looking for, I wanted to read line by line from the xml and display that. Please help me on this fairly new to WCF and web services. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**XDocument** does not implements **IXmlSerializable**.You can also transfer a string instead of the XDocument and parse it in client side.

Change your method like this

```
 public string GetXMLData(string value)
 {
     // XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(Properties.Resources.Test);
     // return doc.ToString();
     return Properties.Resources.Test;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. But I am getting a compilation error for return XDocument.ToString();
saying An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'object.ToString()

Comment: Should be doc.ToString(); ??

Comment: @user3495554 Edited the answer.  It should have been `doc.ToString()` except, there is no reason to parse a string to an XML object, and then spit it back out.  Just return the original string.

Comment: @Seymour, yes it is...but when I do view in browser .svc http://localhost:12345/TestXML.svc/MyHttpGetData it's a blak page

Comment: This is were I implemented the interface which I believe that I am not passing the Get correctly [OperationContract] [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "GetXMLData/{value}")] string GetXMLData(string value); }

Comment: @Sajeetharan, can you help me please? It's the Iservice part not displaying the xml in the browser.